# How to prevent data changes in array which is available in appdelegate in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi in my application i am getting the data from server and storing that data in a array and that array i am adding to another array(This array i declared in appdelegate file ). In this manner i am adding so many arrays in appdelegates array. At first it is good and each array count which are available in appdelegate array is expecting result only, but after some time the array's count is changing which are available in this appdelegate array. why it is happening i don't have any idea. if any one have any idea please let me know. Otherwise please suggest any other procedure to store data in this manner like plist or sqlite like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some code or we will not be able to help. As a suggestion - do you really need to store all the data in RAM? If not, you should use plist or database, as you said.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply i am unable to post code because it's very lenghty so i am posting the flow 


Server call 1 :

Getting Data from server ------> store in Array1 (count 6)


Array1 add to ------> Appdelegate.FinalArray  


Server call 2:

Array reintialization


Getting Data from server ------> store in Array1 (count 9)


Array1 add to ------> Appdelegate.FinalArray

Comment: Server call 3: 

Array1 reintialization 


Getting Data from server ------> store in Array1 (count 19)
Array1 add to ------> Appdelegate.FinalArray
In this manner we will  get the data from the server and store in array1 that will add to App delegate.FinalArray
Now if i print the arrays counts which are available in Appdelegate.FinalArray 
I am getting result as 6 9 19.
But after sometime if i print .
I am getting 19 0 1
Like this i don't know why the data is changing in the array.
And i want keep this upto app terminate that's why i am storing in the array which is available in app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly are you storing the data in this way and why do you have to use so many Server calls? 
Is there no way to just receive a structured file from the server (e.g. xml) which gives you all the results from the different calls?
This would make the whole process a lot easier because the data can be parsed in one call and can be put in a neat core data/plist structure.

Comment: hi Amandir i have a projects in server related each filter so for getting projects related to each filter i have to send in this manner.